# php ImageMagick with MAMP Pro 3 on localhost — exec not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, localhost, mamp-pro

I’ve installed ImageMagick locally via MAMP Pro 3. “phpinfo” shows that Imagemagick is installed.

My Problem is, that I don’t know how to execute it via php.

Here is what I’ve already tried:

```
exec("convert original.png generated.png");
exec("/usr/bin/php_safemode/convert original.png generated.png");
exec("/usr/local/bin/convert original.png generated.png");
exec("convert ".__DIR__."/original.png ".__DIR__."/generated.png");
exec("/usr/bin/php_safemode/convert ".__DIR__."/original.png ".__DIR__."/generated.png");
exec("/usr/local/bin/convert ".__DIR__."/original.png ".__DIR__."/generated.png");
```

NONE of those commands are working. I’ve searched the whole web for solutions … but without success. Wasted a whole day.
(I’ve also tried this thing with envars … without success)

Thought maybe you can help me?
THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by myself — path has to be "**/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/**"

This works for me:

```
exec("/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/convert original.png generated.png");
```

:)